# How to replicate a user clicking a React component using pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, react-select

I'm having some trouble testing the [react-select](https://react-select.com/) library using Selenium.

Amongst other things, it's a fancy select box that pops open a list of entries when you click on it, as shown below.

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't trigger this behavior with JavaScript in my tests or, by extension, the JS console.

To see what I mean visit [this page](https://react-select.com/) and interact with the component yourself in the console. You can get a reference to one of them with:

```js
var select = document.querySelector(".basic-single")
```

I've tried:

```js
select.click()
select.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"))
```

My understanding has run out here, so I wonder how I should proceed. Ideally I'd like an answer as well as a workflow I can use to debug these problems myself in Chrome devtools (or equivalent)

Comment: How about `select.onClick(new Event(...))`? I don't know how you would construct a synthetic event object (like react usually provides), but I don't think React relies on event listeners or the events API for `on{Event}` properties—those properties are more of a native browser API.

Comment: `new Event("click", {bubbles: true})`

Comment: No luck with the comments so far (but cheers anyway)